# Manipulate string problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a string variable with value as follows :-

```
string mystring = "TYPE1, TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE2, TYPE3, TYPE3, TYPE4, TYPE4";
```

and I want to manipulate this string and make it as follows:-

```
string mystring = "TYPE1,TYPE2,TYPE3,TYPE4";
```

ie I want to just remove all the duplicates in it, how should I do it?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Which .net version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var parts = mystring.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).Distinct().ToList();
string newString = String.Join(",", parts);
```

Comment: I tried yours, the result is coming as "TYPE1,TYPE1,TYPE2,TYPE3,TYPE4". Why is Type1 appearing twice? cant igure out

Comment: That's because the first TYPE1 has a space before it and the seconds doesn't. I fixed the code, it should work now.

Comment: thanks..its working fine now but there's one problem. There's a comma at the end. How to remove that?

Comment: Just tried it, there is no comma at the end. I used the definition of mystring you have posted in your question. Please show your code.

Comment: I have sorted it out myself. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

Well, here's a LINQ approach:

```
string deduped = string.Join(",", original.Split(',')
                                          .Select(x => x.Trim())
                                          .Distinct());
```

Note that I'm using `Trim` because your original string has a space before each item, but the result doesn't.

`Distinct()` doesn't actually *guarantee* that ordering will be preserved, but the current implementation does so, and that's also the most natural implementation. I find it hard to imagine that it will change.

If you're using .NET 3.5, you'll need a call to `.ToArray()` after `Distinct()` as there are fewer `string.Join` overloads before .NET 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
string mystring = "TYPE1, TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE2, TYPE3, TYPE3, TYPE4, TYPE4";

var split = mystring.Split(',');
var distinct = (from s in split select s).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

### One liner

```
string result = string.Join(",", mystring.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).Distinct());
```

### Ordering?

You can as well add `OrderBy()` in the line to sort your strings if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go for the Linq option in Jon Skeet's answer, so I've also upvoted that, but just to give you another other option

```
List<string> parts = new List<String>();
foreach(string split in mystring.Split(','))
    if(!parts.Contains(split))
        parts.Add(split);

string newstr = "";
foreach(string part in parts)
    newstr += part + ",";
```

This will work in older versions of C# too.

Comment: You should probably go with `HashSet` and `StringBuilder` instead in this example.

Comment: I was just giving another option. If you have any more, please submit them as answers.